# What is a good verb to be used with ‘possibilities’ in this context?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

> After showing all the restrictions, I will investigate the
> possibilities that still … for activism.

The verbs coming to my mind are **hold** and **maintain**. But I don’t know if these are good choices, and which one is better.

Comment: Here, "good choices" (or "better words") depend on your situation ; Without context, I think, these are available : **exist, remain, stand-out, allow, persist**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Maintain" is not proper. "Hold" would do depending on the context; if, for instance, you are considering a set of legal possibilities that result from a certain politics, and if in a particular case, certain legal restrictions are added to change these, then the nature of  those resulting possibilities is compatible with the use of "hold".

> (OED) be or remain valid, apply

- After showing all the restrictions, I will investigate the possibilities that still *hold* for activism.

If, instead, the possibilities are not the very articles of the law, but the particular activities that these laws take into account, "hold" is not a very good choice. In such a case a more precise verb  would be  "obtain".

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/obtain?q=obtain)) **obtain** **2** ​[intransitive] (not used in the progressive tenses)
> (of rules, systems, customs, etc.) to exist

> (SOED) **obtain** **6** *v.i.* be prevalent, customary, or established; subsist, hold good,be in force or in vogue.

- After showing all the restrictions, I will investigate the possibilities that still *obtain* for activism.

Note that this verb could also be used in the first context.